# gradle plugin lint error when format string res

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I have a string res and kotlin data class below:

`<string name="amount_format">¥%1$.2f</string>`

```
data class TagAndTotal(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tag_name") var tagName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total") var total: Float)
```

I got error below when I run `./gradlew lint` after I upgrade to AGP 3.1.0.

```
Error: Wrong argument type for formatting argument '#1' in 
amount_format: conversion is 'f', received <ErrorType> (argument #2 in 
method call) [StringFormatMatches]
        applicationContext.getString(R.string.amount_format, it.total))
```

But it's no error in AGP 3.0.1.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same problem. Declare an explicit local variable with type solve my problem.

In your case, could you try:

```kotlin
val total : Double = it.total
applicationContext.getString(R.string.amount_format, total)
```

I think this is a bug in AGP

Comment: This is still a bug in Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.2 and this solution still works

Comment: This is still a bug in Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.1 and this solution still works

Comment: This happens with AGP 7.3.0 when using fields from Java classes. This fix still works

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in AGP - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169751286

It was fixed in 4.1.0-alpha08.

At the moment of writing the most "stable" release with a fix is 4.1.0-rc03.